# Piezo buzzer : transient audible noise when exciting over 20kHz

Tags: piezo, piezo-buzzer

Let's 2 simple experiments, connect a piezo buzzer like [this one](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Adafruit/1739?qs=GURawfaeGuAEBLNjCOj9Gw==&vip=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2IrmBRCJARIsAJZDdxDCBv_AjGTdJ8D4lrRXEjfS-pS0ova3nQOjZ45jkgxNpMWDXCb1IFwaAo7BEALw_wcB) to a bench amplifier driven by a function generator [like this one](http://flcelectronics.com/f20a.html). Driving voltage is 10V. Now excite it with a

- linear chirp from 300Hz to 20kHz with a 500ms duration : you will
  hear some noise, it's normal, we excite audible range
- linear chirp from 40kHz to 200kHz : you will
  hear 2 transient audible noise at the beginning/end of the
  excitation. Loudness is small but we can hear it.

In second case, how can we generate audible noise when exciting over audible range with an analog signal ?

Comment: There's a resonance at 1300Hz per the datasheet https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Adafruit%20PDFs/1739_Web.pdf  The transient at start and end is probably exciting that.

Comment: Also, if the amplitude envelope has fast edges, the sidebands created thereby can extend down into the audible range.

Comment: The resonance is triggered by the DC step at start and stop.

Comment: And to suppress it, what type of signal processing do you recommend?